# ICS file with VALARM is not triggering alarm in Google calendar

Tags: icalendar

I have a simple .ics file with some events. The file can be imported to Google calendar locally or via web URL and that is working fine.

But if I add an alarm in the event structure, the Google calendar ignores that alarm.

The structure of ics:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//icalendar test v1.0//cs-CZ
BEGIN:VEVENT
STATUS:CONFIRMED
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20220519
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20220519
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
SEQUENCE:0
UID:40792022
DTSTAMP:20220519T181146Z
SUMMARY:Testing
DESCRIPTION:test
PRIORITY:1
CLASS:PUBLIC
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20220519T152000
DESCRIPTION:test
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

In Google cal. settings there is an option to enable alarm some minutes before the event or for fullday events (my case) to set a date and hour to show alarm.

But as I want to show alarm only for some events, that's why I have VALARM defined in ics file, but it doesn't trigger any alarm.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a problem with Google Calendar itself? You can validate anyway the file if you want.

Comment: the file is valid, I found out that Google manages its own alarms manually set in calendar and ignores the alarms from the custom files, to avoid duplicate alarms or so